# Non-linear trend

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

Would you please help me to fit the following data?
The data is monthly. I have done in R the following but I don't know how to explain /366

```
xc<-cos(2*pi*mydata$months/366)
fit.lm <- lm(mydata$y~xc)
summary(fit.lm)
```

Comment: `mydata$dummy <- as.integer(mydata$month %in% 11:12)`.

Comment: How did you decide 366? By intuition? Trial?

Comment: I  guessed 366. I do not know if it is correct or no.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of various statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: @ALRADDADI I think you can't explain it because it is a case base situation. Also, when you choose 365 or 367 nothing will change. It is just your decesion that your data is following that sort of trend. Actually, when a linear trend is put inside in a model (which is more common ), in reality, it is also nothing but an assumption! People use that because they assume that their data is following a linear trend wrt to shape of the plot.